# Accessing child elements with respect to checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have a list of User Details which option to select, [as shown here - **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jSsc/30/), now I want to Get the selected Users and fetch corresponding Text-box values .

For getting selected users I have a simple jQuery:-

```
var selected = new Array();
$('.dummy-class ').click(function (e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        selected.push(this);
    } else {
        var index = selected.indexOf(this);
        selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(selected);
});
```

Now, I got confused how do I select the elements lying inside.

```
//Access values of selected elements while saving and creating OBJECT
$('.SaveDetails').click(function () {
    console.log(selected);
    var tempArray = [];
    $.each(selected, function (index, value) {
        console.log($(this).find("input:first").attr("value"));//Its not working

        var temp = {};
        temp.FirstName = $(this).find("input:first").attr("value");"));//Its not working
        tempArray.push(temp);
    });
    console.log(tempArray);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `.panel` element in which the checkbox is present and then the input element with name `first` inside it.

```
var selected = new Array();
$('.dummy-class ').change(function (e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        selected.push(this);
    } else {
        var index = selected.indexOf(this);
        selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(selected);
    var $panel = $(this).closest('.panel');
    console.log($panel.find('input[name="first"]').val())
});
```

You will have to make sure all the name fields have the name `first`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5bqXq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to use inside `$('.SaveDetails').click(function ()` handler then try this:

```
$('.SaveDetails').click(function () {
    console.log(selected);
    var tempArray = [];
    $.each(selected, function (index, value) {
        console.log($(this).closest('.panel').closest('.panel').find("input:first").val());//Its not working

        var temp = {};
        temp.FirstName = $(this).closest('.panel').find("input:first").val();"));//Its not working
        tempArray.push(temp);
    });
    console.log(tempArray);
});
```